# Sub Pie menu auto open

Tags: python

How does Blender make the sub pie menu nested in the main pie menu "hover" in the button, and then delay the automatic opening.

For example, my main pie menu is bound with the right mouse button, and I use the sub pie menu nesting. I must execute the "right mouse button release" operation to open the sub pie menu. This operation means that I cannot use Muscle memory to execute different commands only by pressing and holding the right mouse button.

```
> Class MAIN_PIE_MENU（bpy.types.Menu）： bl_idname = “” bl_label = “”

def draw(self, context):
    pie = self.layout.menu_pie()
    op = pie.operator("wm.call_menu_pie", text="Sub Pie Menu 1")
    op.name = "SUB_PIE_MENU_1"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.